# How does $ \frac{\sqrt{x}\left(2ax+b\right)-\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{2\sqrt{x}}}{x} $ become $ \frac{3ax^2+bx-c}{2x^{3/2}} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

The original question was: Differentiate the given function with respect to x:
$$
f(x) = \dfrac{ax^2+bx+c}{\sqrt{x}}
$$

I simplified till
$$
\dfrac{\sqrt{x}\left(2ax+b\right)-\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{2\sqrt{x}}}{x}
\tag1$$
then the next step simplified it into
$$
\dfrac{2ax+b}{\sqrt{x}}-\dfrac{ax^2+bx+c}{2x^\frac{3}{2}}
\tag2$$
then finally into
$$
\dfrac{3ax^2+bx-c}{2x^\frac{3}{2}}  
\tag3$$

Can someone explain the simplification?

Comment: Multiply the first term by $\frac{2x}{2x}$ to get a common denominator ....

Answer (score 1):

Let $\color{green}{x>0}$. We have $$
\dfrac{\sqrt{x}\left(2ax+b\right)-\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{2\sqrt{x}}}{x}
=\frac{A-\frac{B}{C}}{D}=\frac{A}{D}-\frac{\frac BC}{D}$$ where A, B, C and D are 4 clearly defined numbers.

Then you use$$\frac{\frac BC}{D}=\frac{\frac BC}{\frac {\color{red}{D}}1}=\frac BC.\frac 1{\color{red}{D}}=\frac{B}{CD}$$with $CD=\boxed{2\color{Purple}{\sqrt x} .x=2\color{Purple}{x^{\frac12}}x^1=2x^{\frac12+1}=2x^{\frac32}}$

And you end by following the advice of @true blue anil. You will obtain$$\frac{2x(2ax+b)-ax^2-bx-c}{2x^{\frac32}}$$

---

Note for $\frac AD$  that you can write $x=\sqrt x\times\sqrt x $ since $\color{green}{x>0}$.